# Extension of premeasure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

This is a question from homework. I think it is somehow connected to caratheodory's extension theorem, but I don't know how to start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is true. With apologies for wimping out and writing $A_n$ for that algebra:

Let $X=\mathbb R$. Let $A_n$ be the algebra generated by the intervals $$I_{n,k}=(k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}]\quad(k\in\mathbb Z).$$So in fact $A_n$ is just the set of countable unions of those intervals; convenient.

Define $\mu_n$ by $$\mu_n(I_{n,0})=1,$$
$$\mu_n(I_{n,k})=0\quad(k\ne0).$$

(Note that $\mu_{n+1}(I_{n,0})=\mu_{n+1}(I_{n+1,0}\cup I_{n+1,1})
=1=\mu_n(I_{n,0})$ and similarly $\mu_{n+1}(I_{n,k})=0=\mu_n(I_{n,k})$ for $k\ne0$, as required.)

If $\mu$ is as in the problem then $$\mu(I_{n,0})=1$$for every $n$, so continuity from above shows that $\mu(\emptyset)=1$.

Comment: I wish whoever would say what the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

By Caratheodory's extension theorem, you only have to prove the existence of $\mu$ on the ring $\mathfrak A$ generated by $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathfrak A_n$ and show that $\mu|_{\mathfrak A}$ is a pre-measure, i.e. satisfies countable additivity. Two questions naturally arise :

- Is $\mathfrak A \overset{def}{=} \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mathfrak A_n$ a ring?
- How would you define $\mu|_{\mathfrak A}$?
- Does it satisfy countable additivity?

Hope that helps,

Comment: Have you thought about the details in showing $\mu$ is a measure?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich There are some, but I am giving advice, not answers! I am assuming the question is correctly formulated though (I just saw your answer which claims this is wrong).

Comment: It seemed obviously right to me until I started thinking about the details. (The question _is_ correctly formulated -  it says prove or disprove.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : Then my answer is still "correct", in the sense that those are the questions that should naturally arise! Since $\mu$ is already define on $\mathfrak A_n$, the question is how do we define it on $\mathfrak A$, and you saw that there is an issue when trying to show that $\mu|_{\mathfrak A}$ is a pre-measure. (However, $\mu|_{\mathfrak A}$ is a well-defined *content*. See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_(measure_theory))

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : When people say they are doing homework, you usually don't want to give them a complete answer. I gave my first thoughts on the question : sometimes it is also good to give pointers if you already know the answer. Nevertheless, good example.

Comment: @Patric Da Silva , I'm willing to learn advanced mathematics . please do some favour, sir...

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Hi Patrick, apologies, but this is the only way I could contact you. Is there a better way? Cheers